# Can a CD disk and the memory of a device have an infinite space storage?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

I’m asking this because, I’m thinking that it is possible to make a CD or ps vita cd to have an infinite space storage so that new updates will come.

And, it is possible for the company Sony to make the new memory of ps vita to be infinite space storage?

Can anyone tell me if it is possible for a company to do that?

Out of curiosity.

Sorry if I have asked in a wrong site and for adding this tags, you can edit this post.

Comment: This is off-topic here, but be assured that nothing in life is truly infinite.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus if you think it is “not about” computer science, then there’s a site where I can ask this question?

Comment: Perhaps [electronics.se].

Comment: Only moderators can migrate questions. You can flag your question for migration.

Comment: Thanks for flagging this. I'm going to decline to migrate this, because I don't know the scope of EE.SE well enough to know whether this is suitable there, and because I can't tell whether this question is really about electronics and electrical engineering.  (Actually, I can't really tell what is being asked; what does it mean to ask if it can have infinite storage?  Nothing has infinite storage.  What's the real problem you are trying to solve?  Why are you asking?)

Comment: You are free to look at [their help page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), see whether you think it is suitable, and if yes, post it there.  However, I'd caution that I'm not sure whether you're likely to get a good reaction to the question in its current form -- asking about "infinite storage space" doesn't seem realistic to me, so it makes me wonder if your real question is perhaps something else.

Comment: @D.W. I was asking this because, I think there might be ways in future that we( humans) might be able to make the cd or the storage of a device to be infinite. I was only wondering if it will be possible, that’s all.

Comment: Rather than telling me, I'd suggest you use that to improve your question, if you decide to ask it elsewhere.

Comment: @D.W. “Improve the question”? What is that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible.

Storing information requires physical space and there is a limit. This might seem somewhat obscured by the fact that we can store a lot of information in a small space, by the technological process which brought us smaller and smaller storage devices and by other factors which make the relationship between information and space less clear (e.g. a 700MB CD and a 50GB Blu-Ray disk have the same volume).

The limit on how much information can be stored is given by the [Bekenstein bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound):

$I \le \frac{2 \pi c R m}{\hbar ln2} $

$I$ is the information quantity that can be stored in a sphere with radius $R$ and mass $m$.

In short, you need an infinite amount of space to store an infinite amount of information, but a CD has a finite volume.

Comment: It is impossible maybe because, we are not highly advanced for this? Or, no matter how much advanced we are still it is impossible?

Comment: @AlexA It is impossible, no matter how advanced our technology will become.

Comment: You are right. That’s what I thought only